# ¿Como crear una carpeta dentro de "res" para añadir imagenes android studio?

Tags: android

No encuentro la manera de crear una carpeta dentro de "res" en android studio, tengo muchas imágenes y necesito tenerlas organizadas de mejor manera, añadir ciertas imágenes dentro de una carpeta lo solucionaría,el problema es que no encuentro solución.

Comment: Bienvenido para que sea bien recibida tu pregunta lee **[ask]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine que quieres crear una carpeta llamada "Noche" en RES.

1: Click derecho en res.

2: Después ve a New.

3: Después ve a Folder.

4: Después ve a Res Folder Option y selecciona.

Una ventana se abrirá.

5: En esa ventana, pincha en la caja "Change Folder Location", asumiendo que vamos a crear la carpeta "Noche".

6: Así que nombra la nueva carpeta creada como "Noche", en el siguiente formato: src/main/res/Noche

7: Pulsa finish.

Comment: Si se crea la carpeta, el problema es que solo es visible cuando pongo la vista en modo Project, agregue una imagen a dicha carpeta y al tratar de acceder  a esta desde java y xml no se encuentra.

Answer (score -1):

Simplemente ubica el directorio `/res` da click en botón derecho y selecciona "New" y posteriormente "Directory", con esto es suficiente para crear un nuevo folder.

En vista de proyecto tipo "Project":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En vista de proyecto tipo "Android":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.