# ¿Cómo crear subcarpetas dentro de directorio res/drawable?

Tags: android

Tengo muchas imagenes y necesito organizarlas de mejor manera, para ello seria muy util crear carpetas donde podiera almacenarlas por categorias, no consigo hacerlo, he realizado busquedas y la solucion frecuente  es:
Añadir las imagenes asignandoles una nomenclatura.

img_a

img_b

img_c

Comment: A que tipo de categorías te refieres?

Comment: ¿Esta pregunta ya la realizaste?: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157762/como-crear-una-carpeta-dentro-de-res-para-a%C3%B1adir-imagenes-android-studio

Comment: Mira, tengo muchas imagenes en drawable y quiero añadir unas cuantas en una carpeta.

Comment: Creo que estas malinterpretando, lo que sucede es que los folders /drawable almacenan imagenes dependiendo del tamaño. Aquí no aplica categorias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, el mecanismo de recursos de Android no es compatible con las subcarpetas del directorio `drawable`, por lo que debes mantener la estructura tal como está.

Agregar subcarpetas causaría que ninguna de las imágenes dentro de ellas esté disponible.

Segùn parece, tener una subcarpeta con cualquier elemento dentro de la carpeta `res/drawable` hará que el compilador de recursos falle, evitando que el archivo `R.java` se genere correctamente.

La que podrías hacer para tener todo más organizado es poner las imágenes con nombres que los categoricen como por ejemplo:

```
res/drawable
-- drawable_grupo_1_img_a.png
-- drawable_grupo_1_img_b.png
-- drawable_grupo_2_img_c.png
```